# How to make a table with expandable (expand and collapse) columns in React (and MUI)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using Material UI table components (which is not more than a styled and convenient API for HTML table elements)  and I want to make my columns expand collapse on click.
This means that I need that when I click on a column, its sub-columns will be visible and all the rows will also show values for the sub-columns, and when I click on the main column again, the sub-columns will collapse and be invisible again, along with all the values in the rows for those sub columns.

I would also like it to be animated with a nice transition of the columns expanding from the main column into view and collapsing into the main column to invisible.

It doesn't necessarily need to be in react or using MUI, it could regular HTML and CSS, but the animations are crucial!

Thank you in advance for the help :)

I tried to use MUI tables components with the Collapse component (which is an animation component to put things into view with a nice transition) but it was neither smooth nor pretty and not even working properly as the columns were sometimes not aligned..

I've looked everywhere on google and couldn't find any example/library for such a feature anywhere.
I was only able to find examples for expand/collapse rows..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My code would not be useful in this case as its basic use of the html table api, I just haven't been able to get it working in a nice way to have transitions and everything